# Cannot view xbox controller with node-hid - Ubuntu 12.04.03

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04

I am trying to view a xbox controller with the node-hid module but whenever I run

```
var HID = require('node-hid');
console.log(HID.devices());
```

it logs a blank array with no devices even though I have a xbox controller plugged in. However, when I run lsusb it show my devices. When I plug in a mouse or keyboard node-hid sees it and returns the info so it seems it just doesnt see my xbox controller. The xbox controller is an off brand controller and has the following info in lsusb.

Device 004: ID 1bad:fa01 Harmonix Music

Comment: https://github.com/hanshuebner/node-hid/issues/43

Comment: Perhaps this issue is related but they don't seem to be able to return anything at all, while I just can't get it to return my Xbox controller. It can return a mouse or a keyboard just fine. I might try loading up a OSX machine and running a few tests there.